# When’s a right time for a 20 something college graduate to make their bank account independent of their parents?

Tags: united-states, bank-account, college

When’s a good time for someone working on their masters subsidized by their parents, and income from a job that doesn’t make too much money  to break the joint bank account with their parents and have an independent bank account?
Their parents aren’t in debt so they don’t have to worry about debt collectors.

Comment: On your 18th birthday.

Comment: What if I don’t feel financially independent? I’m getting economically subsidized for tuition. I haven’t gotten a high paying job that I feel like I’ve made money out of my own ability.

Comment: That's okay. Your parents can still help you out, while you learn to manage your own money, even if you don't have a lot of it. If your parents really want to be able to claw back the money they send you, you can have two accounts, one shared and one your own.

Comment: Is that how joint accounts work if the holders are adults in regards to clawing?

Comment: I can’t claw their money under the bank I’m using.

Comment: Either owner of a joint bank account can deposit or withdraw funds equally. Regarding financial independence, you can learn to manage money equally well if you earn the money yourself or if your parents provide the money. You can sit down with them to work out a monthly budget that addresses your needs, and they can give you a lump sum once per month. It will be up to *you* to make sure you don't run out of money before the month is up.

Comment: @chepner quite true.  In college, my father gave me $400/mo and that had to pay for all monthly expenses, including food, rent, gas and fun.  Thus, I was forced to budget (which, honestly, it not that mentally challenging: list your expenses, add them up and make sure the sum is less than your income.)

Answer (score 3):

(This is an opinion question, and Money.SE really frowns upon them, so I'm making it a Community answer.  To be quite honest, this is a better question for InterpersonalSkills.SE.)

> When’s a good time for someone **working on their masters** subsidized by their parents, **and income from a job** that doesn’t make too much money to break the joint bank account with their parents and have an independent bank account?

As soon as you got a job.

However...

> subsidized by their parents

Would that emotionally hurt your parents?  I *metaphorically* pushed my kids out the door when they graduated HS, but some parents are not only very clingy, but petty.

For example, yours **might** cut off support if you exert some independence.

Or... they might be clingy, and you might be afraid that they'd cut off support, **but they wouldn't.**

We don't know.

What you **can** do is open a new account, and slowly move all activity to that account.

Comment: Having your parents pay for a degree is emotionally hurtful?

Comment: @Germania you misunderstand.  Showing independence hurts **some** parents.  Think helicopters.